# Why does my app not load the translation files of the lib

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, click-packages

I have an click app that depend on some lib,
and i have package that lib in the click package.
the lib loaded well. but the translations file (.mo) are not founded.
my click file free look like this:

```
/
/share
/share/locale/<LANG>/LC_MESSAGES/somlib.mo
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/somelib.so
```

Of course, there is more files, but that what i think that relevant for the question.

i also try to put it on `/usr/share/locale/<LANG>/LC_MESSAGES/somlib.mo`

but what i have found, that the lib try to find the translations files on **real** `/usr/share/locale/...` what i do not have access to it, with click package to put files there...
*(i copy the files to this path with `mv`, and it is work)*

I tried to use `strace` to know where that lib look for his files, but i don't know how to do it on the phone (using emulator). 
trying `strace qmlscene` gave me error that i have to connect to mir server, or something like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory where gettext will search for translations for a particular translation domain is controlled by the [`bindtextdomain`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/bindtextdomain.3.html) function.  The library most likely has a call to this function somewhere in its initialisation routines.  So two options you could try are:

1. Modify the library so the `bindtextdomain` call specifies a directory based on `$APP_DIR`.  So where the library might run:

   ```
   bindtextdomain (PACKAGE, PACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR);
   ```

   You might change it to something like:

   ```
   const char *app_dir = getenv("APP_DIR");
   if (app_dir) {
       char *localedir = NULL;
       asprintf(&localedir, "%s/share/locale", app_dir);
       bindtextdomain(PACKAGE, localedir);
       free(localedir);
   } else {
       /* Not running as a click package: use compiled in default */
       bindtextdomain(PACKAGE, PACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR);
   }
   ```
2. Make a second call to `bindtextdomain` that will run after the library's initialisation that sets the correct directory for the library's translation domain (possibly using code similar to the above).

It is hard to offer any more advice without knowing more about the specifics.

Comment: first of all ,thank you. 1. that mean that i have to recompile the lib?  2.  [this](https://github.com/avi-software/hebrew-calendar-qml/tree/dev) is my code, you can give me a hint were to put that? additionally, if the bindtextdomain path is `/usr/share/locale/...` it should not be within the environment of the app?

Comment: (1) would require recompiling the library, yes.  Looking at the library source http://sourceforge.net/p/libhdate/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/libhdate/src/hdate_strings.c#l281 it looks like it is calling `bindtextdomain` every time that function is called, so it doesn't look like (2) will be possible.

Comment: i tried to add this. i don't know what `APP_ID` is looking for... because that no work. and i can't run strace ... if i add second call to `bindtextdomain` with  `char *localedir ="/opt/click.ubuntu.com/hebrew-calendar.avisoftware/current/share/locale";` that work, you think it is good solution?

Comment: The `APP_DIR` environment variable is set to the directory where your application is installed, which is why I suggested using that to construct the locale directory you pass to bindtextdomain.  That way you don't have to depend on the exact install location.

Comment: something strange, the `APP_DIR` from the app return the correct path `/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/hebrew-calendar.avisoftware` but, from the lib it is not return this.. what is returns? i don't know....

Comment: Environment variables are global to a process, so `getenv("APP_DIR")` in a library is going to return the same thing as if you call it in the main program.  This shouldn't be a problem if you've installed the library's translations into your application's directory.

Comment: you right! now it is work for me. i don't know why it doesn't worked until now. so, thank you very much.